# Encrypting Password

Tags: jquery, encryption

I want to encrypt password in JQuery and decrypt it in servlets. Please tell me which algorithm should I use and how to implement this thing.

Comment: Ideally you should use only 1-way encryption for passwords. In other words, never decrypt them.

Comment: It is not really encryption you use with passwords but hashing.

Comment: @Rahul and whatnick: true, but you should do that on the server, otherwise its like creating random passwords, and transfering them in plain text over thew wire.

Comment: Can you use https/ssl for the transfer to the server? As said before, on the server you should convert the password to a salted hash.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use HMAC.

Basically, you send 2 salts to the client. You store in your database

`md5(salt + pwd)`

you send a unique salt2 and the db salt to the end user, who returns

`md5(salt2 + md5(salt + pwd))`

and then you compare to that same operation server-side.

As long as you vary the salt sent and don't accept old ones, it is about as secure as you're going to get without SSL. You definitely don't want to try to use AES or RSA anything similar.

If you don't like md5, use any other hashing algorithm of your choice.

Comment: Just as I was adding the yahoo sample.

Comment: md5() is not secure, and should be change to sha256() or above (at the moment of writing this)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of how to implement it, things have moved on since the question came up and it looks like CryptoJS should make it easy:

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

NOTE - I haven't used it yet!

Answer (score 0):

A simple spot of Googling would have got you the [answer](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1575). The available algorithms seem to be Blowfish, SHA and Rc4. If you want decryption blowfish would be the way to go. For smaller datasets you can use rc4.

For a practical example look at how Yahoo does its [logins](https://s.yimg.com/lq/i/reg/js/login_md5_1.1.js). The login form has a hidden field which acts as the salt called ".challenge",  this is embedded in the hash as follows:
    
      `fullhash=MD5(MD5(passwd)+challenge)`

Comment: SHA is not encryption but hashing, so you cannot use that. Blowfish, AES, RC4, tripleDES are the most common encryption algorithms

Comment: @Henri: I would rather hash a password than encrypt in terms of web pages.

Comment: @Henri: I was just commenting on the available plugins for Jquery and @Zed yes hashing is the way to go. The OP might just want to be able to recover the passwords.

Comment: One-way hashes are not enough. You must use some form of asymmetric cypher such as RSA. You can can combine RSA with a one-way hash, but RSA (or similar) must be part of the package, otherwise an attacker can hack your site (from a cryptographic point of view)

Comment: Steve: support your assertions. A one-way hash is perfectly secure for this sort of thing if it's properly salted. MD5 might be a bit broken, but SHA or any of the more modern ones aren't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic encryption problem. The one-way hashes described by whatnick will work but there are security issues. Notably an attacker can perform a replay attack as the hash cannot be salted, meaning the user can only ever send the one hash that corresponds to the hast stored in the database. In other words, this is almost the same thing as sending the password in plain text.

The only way to do this properly is with a non-symmetric public key cypher such as RSA. I have seen a [Javascript implementation here](http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/). I would argue that this is more complicated than necessary and that just doing a secure login via SSL is most probably the safest and easiest thing in the long run.